# long-term behaviour of the system

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

$$A=  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0.30 & 0.40 \\
   0.70 & 0.60 \\
  \end{array}} \right]
$$

long-term behavior of the system with a vector of b.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the given $A$ is the [transition probability matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix#Definition_and_properties) of a Markov chain.

The long-term behavior means the distribution of the state the chain is in when the number of transitions goes to infinity. The distribution after $n$ steps is calculated as

$$A^nc,$$
where c is the initial distribution (the probabilities of starting in each state).

For "nice" chains like this particular one, the long-term behavior doesn't depend on the initial distribution and can be calculated, for example, as the eigenvector of $A$ with the eigenvalue $1$. (That eigenvector has all entries of the same sign and it must be scaled to sum to $1$).

**PS.** Notice: in Wikipedia (and also elsewhere sometimes) stochastic matrices are the transposes of how your matrix is (in your matrix columns sum to one). This means you use the usual eigenvectors, Wikipedia uses the left eigenvectors.

Comment: I have $$x_0 vector $$, should I start to multiply $$x_1 = A * x_0 $$ and their result is going to be multiplied as x_2 = $$A * x_1$$  and so on?

Comment: @TheWho Yes, what that results to is $A^n * x_0$. That will approach the steady-state (long-term) behavior. Are you familiar with Markov chains?

Comment: Yes, I am calculating Markov Chain for the long term by taking the power of matrix A multiply with the initial vector. So I am going to analyze these changes right?

Comment: @TheWho Finding out the long term distribution (the steady state distribution) can be done via eigenvectors. See for example this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvXe4rTGCQo